# How to make a hole in a wall in opengl

Tags: c, opengl

I need to setup a room in opengl. For the walls, I'm thinking of making them with quads, but how can i make a hole (window) on it? because I need a light coming through that window to iluminate the room.

Any idea guys?

Comment: I will reassure you by saying that in OpenGL light will go right through your walls, so you do not actually need a window :) Well, there is no shadowing in OpenGL by default, you will need to implement a shadowing technique yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You already answered the question yourself!

Instead of just have 1 quad as a whole wall, you would split it into multiple quads, there by creating a hole/holes.

Here is a visual representation of how you could do it:

On the left we have a wall made from 1 quad, and on the right we have a wall made from 4 quads, which will have a hole in the center.

[image: image 1]

Though if you want a wall with more depth, you need more quads than just those 4 quads. So here I've drawn another visual representation for you, I've written quad on all the visible faces. Though remember that there are a lot of "invisible" faces, we also need to create.

Making a wall like this isn't that hard, you can easily calculate all the vertices and connect them info faces.

[image: image 2]

Comment: @AndyG Haha, well Paint + 2 minutes = Those pictures.

Answer (score 1):

With only a single closed quad surface, you can't.

You need to construct (or use a library to construct it for you) a more complex shape that looks like a quad wall on the outside, but with a hole in the middle.

For example, a bunch of rectangle strips might do it, or a bunch of triangle strips (with triangles properly deformed to make a hole like opening near the middle).

Some libraries exist which can do solid transformations.  In such a case, you would construct a rectangular wall, a circular cylinder, and subtract the cylinder from the wall (leaving a circular window).  However, it is difficult to know if such libraries would help you as so little is known about your environment.